# Why does this code not achieve the objective of restoring a Derby database from a backup copy of the database?

Tags: java, derby

I have a JavaFXML application that accesses an embedded Derby database. The database is stored in this file subsystem:

[image]

The directory `db` contains the usual Derby files and directories:

[image]

The Backups directory in fig 1 are copies of `db` that a user can create from the applications GUI. For example:

[image]

What I want to achieve is to be able to select one of the backup files from the GUI and replace the current database contained in `db`. I have verified the integrity of these backups by manually deleting `db` and replacing it with a backup.

The code to try and achieve the objective is:

```
public class NdBkp 
{
  private static Connection conn = null; 
  public final static String SETUP_FILE_PATH = "/AppData/Local/NewdawnTest_old/"; 
  public static final String CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:derby:" + "C:/Users/" + System.getenv("USERNAME") + SETUP_FILE_PATH + "db";
  public static final String BACKUP_FILE_PATH = "C:/Users/" + System.getenv("USERNAME") + SETUP_FILE_PATH + "Backups";

  public static void connect() {
    try {  
//      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL  + ";create=true");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL);   
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
  } 

  public static void commit(){
    try {
      conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static boolean isConnected() {
    try{  
      System.out.println("");
      return (!(conn.isClosed()));
    }
    catch (SQLException | NullPointerException e){ 
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
    }
  }

  public static void disconnect() {
    try {
      if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
        conn = null;
      }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void backUpDatabase(String dirname) {
    try {
      CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE(?)");
      cs.setString(1, BACKUP_FILE_PATH + "/" + dirname);
      cs.execute();
      cs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void restoreDatabase(String backupdirpath) {
    System.out.println("Restoring " + CONNECTION_URL + " from + " + backupdirpath);
    try {
      DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL + ";restoreFrom=backupdirpath");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    String backupdirpath = "C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/NewdawnTest_old/Backups/20200515_bkp_02";
    connect(); 
    restoreDatabase(backupdirpath);
    System.out.println("Is connected is " + isConnected());
    disconnect();
    System.out.println("Is connected is " + isConnected());
 }
}
```

When I compile and run this code, everything appears to work. There is no error dump or any indication that the requested operation defined in the `restoreDatabase` method has not worked. But when I look in the file system, nothing has in fact happened and the current version of `db` has remained unaffected. I cannot figure out why this is and don't know what is missing, so I would appreciate some assistance.

Comment: `catch (SQLException | NullPointerException sqle){ return false; }`? Really?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Thanks for your comment. I don't quite understand how it helps me with the issue I am having. Please elucidate.

Comment: You are catching an exception indicating a problem. Print the stack trace!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose  Yes that was a bad miss by me. However the addition of print stack traces shows no exceptions being thrown when the code is run.

Comment: Well ... That might be. Your code does nothing! What do you expect? Time to debug, I guess ...

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I would expect the code to restore the database from the backup copy.

Answer (score 3):

Might the problem be, that you're just appending the word "backupdirpath" where you should be appending a value of variable referenced by this name?

```
  public static void restoreDatabase(String backupdirpath) {
    System.out.println("Restoring " + CONNECTION_URL + " from + " + backupdirpath);
    try {
      // I think this:
      DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL + ";restoreFrom=backupdirpath");
      // should be this:
      //DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL + ";restoreFrom=" + backupdirpath);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code to minimize the lines and found the error:

```
public class Restore {

  public void restoreDatabaseRoutine() {

          String restoreUrl = "jdbc:derby:Test;restoreFrom=/path/to/another/db";
          String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
          Class.forName(driver);
          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(restoreUrl);
          conn.close();
          System.out.println("The database has been successfully restored");
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `String address` in the methods signature?